# sending email from SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, gmail, gmail-imap

I want to send an email from SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE; I have defibed those properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=nunito.calzada@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=aMdwd3cded2@
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.propertirs.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
and using org.springframework.mail.MailSender
```

I am sending the email using `org.springframework.mail.MailSender`

```
    mailSender.send(mailMessage);
```

Everything seems to be OK, I don't see any exception, any error, but I don't receive email, not even in the SPAM email

I also tried

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 587
```

with the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for Spring Boot add the dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

> Once the dependency is in place, the next step is to specify the mail
>   server properties in the application.properties file using the
>   spring.mail.* namespace.
>
> For example, the properties for Gmail SMTP Server can be specified as:

```
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.host: smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port: 465
spring.mail.username: <user name>
spring.mail.password: <password>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.test-connection=
```

CODE:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender 
private void setMailDetailsForSend( final String payload, final String email ) throws MessagingException
{

    final MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper( mail, true );
    helper.setTo( email );
    helper.setSubject( "Notification" );
    helper.setText( "text/html", payload );
    mailSender.send( mail );

}
```

> Some SMTP servers require a TLS connection, so the property
>   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable is used to enable a
>   TLS-protected connection.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to pass into the constructor of SendMail(String **from**,....),
set:
public void sendMail(String from,
String to,
String subject,
String text,
boolean isHtmlContent) throws MessagingException {
MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

```
    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    **mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(from);**
```

where **from** must be a valid email address of a **sender**, usually the same like your username defined in an **application.properties**:  ...spring.mail.username:<your_username email address>

Answer (score 1):

your property file containing

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
```

gmail work with TSL/SSL

```
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
    Port for SSL: 465
```

i am suggest you use

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 587
```

instead of 465